# What should i do to be able to see what i posted in a category?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

When I post some JSON that contains a category like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 152,
        "image": "https://a",
        "description": "J t",
        "price": "USD 8.70",
        "buy": "https:// 6d7",
        "category": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 153,
        "image": "https://",
        "description": "elf",
        "price": "65",
        "buy": "https://s.c D",
        "category": 1
    }
]
```

in templates, I do not see them.

[image]

html:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="{% static 'main.css' %}">
    <div class="header">
        <img   src="static/logo.png">

 
         
    </div>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: #56454F;">

    

    <div class="grid">  
        {% for i in p%} 
                
                    <div class='card'>
                        <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
                        <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
                        <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                            <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
                        </a>    




                    </div>

        {%endfor%}
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <h1 >&copy All rights reserved</h1>

    </div>   

</body>
</html>
```

models:

```
from django.db import models
 
class category(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class product(models.Model):
     
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    image=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buy=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views:

```
class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = productSerializer 

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = productSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @action (detail=False , methods=['post']) 
    def delete(self,request):
        product.objects.all().delete()
        return Response('success')
def home(request):
    
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':category.objects.all()})

def foods(request):
    
    return render(request,'foods.html',{'p':category.objects.all()})
```

I do not know what should i write in `{'p':category.objects.all()}` to be able to put some data from a specific category to that html code.

What should i do to be able to see what i posted in a category?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass this data in home template, You can do this by just simply:

```
def home(request):
    p = Product.objects.all()
    context = ['p':p]
    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

in the home template you can pass all Product fields with:

```
<div class="grid">  
    {% for i in p%} 
                <div class='card'>
                    <img src="{{i.image}}"></img>
                    <p id="id">{{i.description}}</p>
                    <p>{{i.category}}</p>
                    <a href="{{i.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                        <button><span class="price"> ${{i.price}}</span> buy</button>
                    </a>    
                </div>
    {%endfor%}

def foods(request, pk):
    i = get_objects_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    context ={'i':i}
    return render(request, 'food.html', context)
```

So in food templates you can get your category by:

```
<p>{{i.category}}</p>
```

In your urls:

```
path('food<int:pk>/', views.foods. name='Food'),
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The concept of category for me is i want to have something in home that i do not want it to be appear in foods. If i do what you said then both of home and foods will have the same thing.

Comment: what do you want to be appear in food template ?

Comment: this primary key "1" in  `"category": 1` represents food in categories. I want the data of  json that represents foods be appear in foods template not in both of home and foods.

Comment: You need to add: **get_objects_or_404** method in the food function.